# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column rooms.hotel does not exist LINE 1:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For a reservation form, I'm trying to get all the unavailable rooms for the selected dates. I'm performing this action in the hotels_controller.

**Issue**

I cannot seem to join the rooms with the reservation properly, as I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column rooms.hotel does not exist
LINE 1: ...."room_id" = "rooms"."id" WHERE "accommoda...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  DISTINCT "rooms".* FROM "rooms" INNER JOIN "reservations" ON "reservations"."room_id" = "rooms"."id" WHERE "rooms"."hotel" = $1 AND (reservations.arrival <= '2019-11-22' AND '2019-11-23' < reservations.departure) LIMIT $2):
```

**Code**

hotels_controller

```
@unavailable_rooms = Room.joins(:reservations).where(hotel: hotel).where("reservations.arrival <= ? AND ? < reservations.departure", arrival, departure).distinct
```

models

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :room
end

class Room < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :room_category
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :room_category
end

class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :room_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :rooms, through: :room_categories
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
end

class RoomCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel
  has_many :rooms, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Comment: From what you have posted it doesn't appear that you have `Room` directly associated with `Hotel`, hence the error. Create a migration to add the association and add a `belongs_to :hotel` to your `Room` model.

Comment: Thanks David, this helped!

Comment: I would assume a `Room` has a `hotel_id` anyway, maybe you were just missing the `belongs_to :hotel` in `Room`? Or did you forget to add the `hotel_id` to the rooms table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hotel` is in `Reservation`, not in `Room`, so you have to:

```
Room.joins(:reservations).where(reservations: { hotel: hotel })
```

The `:reservations` in `where` is the table name, not the association name, which in this case is the same.